# 2 questions: Importing data from MySQL data base to Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert, create-table

Q1. My database contains 3 columns: time, value A and value B. The time data is written in the form 00:00:00 and the increment is 1 minute.
When I try to import data ...
cursor.execute (f"SELECT * FROM trffc_int_data.{i};")
instead getting (00:00:00, A, B), I get
(datetime.timedelta(0), 7, 2), (datetime.timedelta(seconds=60), 8, 5), .....

I suppose Python doesn't convert the time right. Any suggestions?

Q2. I have an initial database with the data mentioned above. I need to get the data from the initial database, convert it, and save it to another database.
I'm stuck at a point where data should be saved to a new table.
Here are the sections of the code...

```
# Creating new DB
NewDB = input(" :: Enter the Database name : ")
sqlsynt = f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {NewDB}"
cursor.execute(sqlsynt,NewDB)                 
stdb.commit()

# Creating table and writing the data
cursor.execute (f"USE {NewDB}")
sqlsynt = f"CREATE TABLE {dayinweek} (time TIME, Vehicles INT(3), Pedestrians INT(3))"
cursor.execute (sqlsynt, NewDB, dayinweek) 
#stdb.commit()
sqlsyntax = f"INSERT INTO {NewDB}.{dayinweek} (time, Vehicles, Pedestrians) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"           
cursor.executemany(sqlsyntax, temp_list_day)
```

The program stucks on the last line saying that there is no table 1 in NewDB!

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'test001.1' doesn't exist
```

What's wrong with the code? Maybe the problem is in mixing f and %s formating?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am followin this correctly, you are creating a table called `1`. Digit-only identifiers are not allowed in MySQL, unless the identifier is quoted, as explained [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Your `create table` statement did fail, but you did not notice that error until you tried to `insert`.

You *could* quote the table name, using backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `{dayinweek}` (time TIME, Vehicles INT(3), Pedestrians INT(3))
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO `{NewDB}`.`{dayinweek}` (time, Vehicles, Pedestrians) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
```

Quoting the database name may also be a good idea: the same rules apply as for table names (and this is user input to start with).

But overall, changing the table name seems like a better option, as this makes for cleaner code: how about something like `table1` for example - or better yet, a table name that is more expressive on what kind of data it contains, such as `customer1`, or `sales1`.

Note: your code *is* open to SQL injection, as you are passing user input directly to the database in a `create database` statement. Obviously such information cannot be parameterized, however I would still recommend performing a minimal sanity check on application side beforehand.